# section with half screen fixed, half scroll to content. Then invert section

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

Ok I am trying to create a split screen layout (with flexbox if possible) that will have one container fixed to the left half of the screen while the container on the other half of the screen that holds the article content scrolls. When the end of the content is reached, the entire section should then scroll freely into the next section, which will be the inverse of the first (fixed right, scroll with content on left. There will be four sections inverted until I reach the footer. This JSFiddle is pretty much what I am looking for, I just need to know how to inverse and add the next section so they flow as stated.

http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dtWWA/

This is a rough outline of how each section will be laid out.

http://jsfiddle.net/QMsuD/191/

```css
#container-main {
  background: tan;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#container-gray {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container-black {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#hello {
  background: blue;
  flex: .5;
  align-self: center;
}

#container-nav {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#how {
  background: orange;
}

#are {
  background: purple;
}

#you {
  background: pink;
}

#container-content {
  background-color: beige;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.headings {
  width: 49%;
  align-self: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.articles {
  width: 85%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=container-main>
  <div id="container-gray">
    <div id="container-black">
      <p id="hello">Hello</p>
      <div id="container-nav">
        <p id="how">How</p>
        <p id="are">are</p>
        <p id="you">you</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container-content">
    <h1 class="headings">First heading</h1>
    <article class="articles">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia
      nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
    </article>
    <h1 class="headings">Second heading</h1>
    <article class="articles">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia
      nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
    </article>
    <h1 class="headings">Third heading</h1>
    <article class="articles">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia
      nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
    </article>
    <h1 class="headings">Fourth heading</h1>
    <article class="articles">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia
      nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry the html listed is close to useless without adding the associate css. For some reason I was unable to format it correctly so the code in its entirety is linked to JSFiddle.

Comment: not sure what you're going for, something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/gRJrXw

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: Oh cool. I'll submit as an answer then

Comment: actually now that ive looked at it a bit, I noticed a couple things I am unable to change. Would there be any way to get rid of the internal scroll? So more precisely I am looking for something that will continue to scroll down on the content side even if you're hovering over the fixed side. Would putting the content in the background while somehow "sticking" the fixed side until content has reached the end. Then obviously invert that. Would something like this require Jquery?

Comment: Sorry about that. Still cool to submit that but if you could let me know any edits I can make to get what I'm looking for, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KqLMoL

Comment: Updated my answer with that. It's worth noting `position: sticky` is a new property. It has decent support in modern browsers except for IE 11, works in edge tho. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QMsuD/192/

Ive got this however this doesn't work when i open it in chrome for some reason. Theres no scrolling at all. I basically need the background to scroll the entire time, but the content and fixed halves switch sides when the content ends for a section. This site has pretty much exactly what I'm looking for...

http://melaniedaveid.com/

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback

Comment: I think Coker has it right on the head. Thank you again all!

Comment: Awesome you're welcome. Be sure to accept a solution once you feel the problem is resolved.

Comment: ok i tried to set the width of the aside to 50% to split the screens in half but it appears there is some default margin (?) interfering. If I set it to 47.5 it looks to be right, but there has to be a better way of doing that. And I will be sure to do that, thanks for the speedy replies.

Comment: also, how do I accept a solution?

Comment: Updated my answer re: 50/50 split. It's the little grey checkmark by a solution.

Comment: Awesome thanks. what did you change to accomplish the 50/50 split?

Comment: read the blurb at the top of my answer :)

Comment: ok gotcha. But what is causing that little gap in alignment in the middle. Default margin or something? Any easy way of avoiding that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/RgmRzJ

Comment: That works and looks right but doesn't seem like the proper way of doing it.

Comment: What gap, between the sections? or between main and sidebar? I don't see a gap between main and sidebar. The gap between the sections is the border on section. Just remove that. And what do you mean doesn't seem like the proper way of doing it? doing what exactly?

Comment: the aside container seems to be taking up about 2.5 % more space than the main. Even though they are split in half. Just don't understand why if theyre being split in half, theyre not taking up exactly half of the width. When I change the width of aside to 47.5 on your previous example, it gives the expected results of a 50/50 split screen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/RgmRzJ this is the edit that corrects the 2.5% discrepancy.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry about that, I wasn't paying attention to that alignment between sections. A `flex-basis: 50%` with `box-sizing:border-box` (because of the padding) will split it in half. Updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect, that's it right there

Comment: Hey Michael, I am having trouble sizing the section to fit the entire page. Ive got my basic design and functionality but I need it to be sized responsively where each section takes up the width and height of the screen. I know some of this, if not all can be done with media querys. However I'm wondering why when I try to set the width and height to percentage or vh/vw, the layout breaks and does not scroll correctly. Here is the layout. 
https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/RgmRzJ

Comment: That's going to be quite a bit of work. If you can't figure it out, post it as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a bunch of `flex` rows as your main sections, add `overflow-y: scroll` for the section to scroll, set the sidebar to `position: sticky` to have the whole section scroll even if the mouse is over the content area, then set the content area and sidebar to `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short) to split them in a 50/50 width. Then absolutely position an element inside of that for the content so that the main section will match whatever the height of the sidebar is.

Then to reverse the side the sidebar/content are on, you can use `:nth-child()` with the flex `order` property.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

section {
  max-width: 640px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
}
section:nth-child(even) main {
  order: -1;
}
aside,main {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
aside,.inner {
  padding: .5em;
}
aside {
  background: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
main {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>

  </aside><main>
    <div class="inner">
      main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>

    </div>

  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>

  </aside><main>
    <div class="inner">
      main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>

    </div>

  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>

  </aside><main>
    <div class="inner">
      main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>

    </div>

  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>

  </aside><main>
    <div class="inner">
      main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>

    </div>

  </main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add `#overflow: hidden` to `container-main`, and `overflow: scroll` to `#container-content` to achieve your goal of the right section scrolling while the left section stays static until you reach the end of both.